# minimum_should_match with nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm having some issues with minimum should match terms query.

In my document I have the following mapping for people nested object

```
"people": {
   "type": "nested",
   "properties": {
      "name": {
         "type": "string",
         "index": "not_analyzed"
       }
     }
}
```

I'm trying to use the minimum_should_match nested query. This code resides inside the nested scope:

```
"bool": {
    "should": [
     {
       "terms": {
          "people.name": [
                 "Anna",
                 "Mark",
                 "Joe"
                 ],
           "minimum_should_match": "100%",
            "boost": 3
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

And even if the document with these three names is inside my index, I have no result.

Is the problem related with the nested structure of the people data?
I want to have high score for documents with higher names matching.

I've tried with  `"execution" : "or"` and I got

```
QueryParsingException[[my_db] [terms] query does not support [execution]
```

The only solution that I've found is to separate each name with a different term statement inside the should scope.

Will this affect the query complexity? Sometimes I have to find documents with 30 names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {"nested":
                {"path": "people",
                    "query": {
                        "terms" : {
                            "people.name" :["Anna", "Joe"]
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
      }
    }
```